# F# How to use an anonymous type in place of a full typed Variable

Tags: f#

The following code works - but I am trying to find a way of writing less code

```
let delayOption = new ElementHandleTypeOptions(Delay=15000f)
do! Async.AwaitTask(transferTextBox.TypeAsync(transferAmount, delayOption ))
```

Something like..?  ( obviously this doesn't work )

```
do! Async.AwaitTask(transferTextBox.TypeAsync(transferAmount, (Delay=15000f) ))
```

I am just not sure if I can replace the declaration of a type with a similar structure without actually declaring it. Is that possible?

Comment: If your method accepts `obj` or generic arguments, you can use [anonymous record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records#basic-usage) syntax: 
`{| Delay = 1500f |}`

Comment: I think you're looking for an equivalent of C#'s `new(15000f)` aka target-typed `new` expressions? There isn't one in F#.

Comment: If you do this often, create just a function? `let delay fl = ElementHandleTypeOptions(Delay=fl)`. And later `...TypeAsync(transferAmount, delay 15000f)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare a variable, you can just create the type at the call site

`do! Async.AwaitTask(transferTextBox.TypeAsync(transferAmount, new ElementHandleTypeOptions(Delay=15000f)))`

the `new` is only needed if `ElementHandleTypeOptions` implements `IDisposable` - [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4520746/57883)

Option 2: you can write an [F# extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1523594/57883) on whatever type `transferTextBox` is reducing call-site syntax in favor of that part living elsewhere.